# Is "TV Input Framework" available outside Android TV

Tags: android-tv

Is "TV Input Framework" available outside Android TV, on stock android ? I would like to develop an IPTV player with EPG that works on any Android variation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short unswer is "No".

On "standard" Android You have to implement same parts as in "tv input app" for Android TV: media playback, playlist/channels list handling, setup UI and the rest. Plus those parts from "TV App" on Android TV, like UI for channels/guide/epg navigation, data storage for channels/epg/icons data.
Currently there is no app which provides IPTV playback on standard android and use TIF on Android TV, but there're:

- "*Lazy IPTV*" (and some others) which use same interface on all Android variants (so, no TIF on Android TV)
- "*CumulusTV*", "*TVirl*" (I'm developer of) which adopts TIF for Android TV only