# How to include google cast sdk into AOSP. What are the essential requirements. We want to build custom AOSP for TV that has cast enabled

Tags: android-source, google-cast

Unable to find the solution for Google cast on AOSP

We have gone through documentation, did not do any implementation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cast seems to be a private commercial protocol, so it can't be available in vanilla AOSP code. You can't find in AOSP source code for Google Play Services either, it is installed to devices certificated by Google.

There are 'dark' installs of Google Play Services, from binary files extracted from stock ROMs, see [OpenGApps](https://opengapps.org/). Not sure if Google Cast framework can be added in such way.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866431/1028256), please have a look.